# PHP Array breaking

Tags: php

This works on my test environment, but on my live server there is a later version of PHP which is throwing up an error and breaking my program

The code is

```
$oldFile = fopen("D:/ftpfolderreport/report/" . $last_file, "r");
while(!feof($oldFile))
{
$buffler = fgets($oldFile);
$bufflerArray = explode(",", $buffler);
$key = $bufflerArray[0];
$oldFileArray[$key] = $bufflerArray[1];
}
fclose($oldFile);
```

This line:

```
$oldFileArray[$key] = $bufflerArray[1];
```

Is throwing out this error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\apps\wamp\www\Compliance2\compareFtpReports.php on line 57
```

I think this is to do with how I'm adding the $key variable inside the argument. I've tried it as ["$key"] and ['$key'] but it doesn't like it.

I have tried defining the key variable earlier in the program but still doesn't like it. I've been searching around online but can't find anything of help. Anyone any ideas?

Thanks,
Stephen.

Comment: please show us a line or 2 of your file so we understand what is happening here.

Comment: `print_r` the `$buffler` before exploding the string, to see where it stumbles. A trailing empty line is most likely. Btw, there is also a `file()` function or `SplFileObject` for reading lines.

Comment: It means there is no element with the key `1` in the array `$bufflerArray`;

Comment: use `if(isset($bufflerArray[1])) { $oldFileArray[$key] = $bufflerArray[1]; }`

Comment: `$bufflerArray = explode(",", $buffler); if(count($bufflerArray)<2) continue;`

Comment: Everyone, thanks so much for the Answers, comments. All were helpful and useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add checks for empty

```
if (!empty($bufflerArray[1])) {
   $key = $bufflerArray[0];
   $oldFileArray[$key] = $bufflerArray[1];
}
```